# Dynamic graphs using C# (To be saved as a PNG Format)

Tags: c#, pdf, graph

I have to generate dynamic graphs on the fly, save it as a PNG image format (Transparent background) to be embedded on to a PDF.

The problem is, the graph will not be displayed on a control in the page (without a chart control in the WebForm) and should be generated from an underlying information and should be embedded while creating the PDF.

The libraries for the PDFs and PDF generation is all in place.

I would like to know how to generate a dynamic graph (Bar graph, Pie Graph) 3D or Simple graph without a chart control in place and be able to save it as an image with transparent background (.PNG).

The reason being, the PDF template has numerous layer shading, hence the background around the graph image should be transparent, something similar to the below image.

[image: Possible Graph]

I have tried generating a dynamic bar graph similar to the example in the below link but the Image doesn't look promising

https://2leggedspider.wordpress.com/2004/11/21/generating-a-dynamic-bar-graph-using-aspnet-and-c/

[image: Graph implemented]

Any help regarding the functionality is deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

### Update: Wednesday 16th March 2016

With TaW's answer and updates I have been able to draw the required graph and below is the update with answer to the same question I asked

Add references to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`

Add below namespaces

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

And below method would give you the Pie Chart with smooth edges as shown in the picture

[image: Pie Chart with Smooth Edges]

```
void Create3DPieChart()
        {
            /* Utilize the Chart class available in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting */
            Chart chart = new Chart();
            /* Add a chart area to the chart */
            ChartArea CA = chart.ChartAreas.Add("A1");
            /* Add data series to the chart and specify the type of Series */
            Series S1 = chart.Series.Add("S1");
            S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

            /* Assign points for the Series */
            S1.Points.AddXY(1, 17);
            S1.Points.AddXY(2, 27);
            S1.Points.AddXY(3, 7);
            S1.Points.AddXY(4, 49);

            /* Set chart color and other settings as required */
            chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            CA.BackColor = chart.BackColor;
            CA.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            S1.Points[2]["Exploded"] = "true";

            /*Assign AntiAliasing to Graphics style for smooth edges*/
            chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics;

            /* Set the image path and save the image as PNG format*/
            string imageNameAndPath = string.Concat(Application.StartupPath.Remove(Application.StartupPath.IndexOf("\\bin\\Debug")), 
                                        "/TempImages/Image", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".png");
            chart.SaveImage(imageNameAndPath, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

TaW. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Looks fine to me! Glad to see that the antialiased pixels are indeed semitransparent! (I just checked your image in Photoshop!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the chart won't draw any transparency directly, so we need to workaround..

If you want to create a PNG with transparent background here is what you can do:

```
chart1.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = chart1.BackColor;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap( chart1.ClientSize.Width, chart1.ClientSize.Height);
chart1.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics;
chart1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, chart1.ClientRectangle);
bmp.MakeTransparent(chart1.BackColor);
bmp.Save(yourFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

First we set some areas in the chart to a unique color; if you use fuchsia in your chart (yuck!), pick some other color.

Then we create a `Bitmap` to hold the image.

Now we turn anti-aliasing off for the text; this help to avoid funny colors when we turn the background pixels to tranparent.

Now we tell the chart control to draw itself into our bitmap.

Finally we make all pixels transparent that have our special color.

Now we can save to disk..

You may want to look into setting the dpi resolution and the chart size to make the result look nice in your pdf!

**Update:**

If you want to create the image without acutally showing a `Chart` control, there is no real problem, either. In fact you can even create a `Chart` image in a console application, if you include all necessary namespaces etc..

All you need to do is create the `Chart` in code and set up all necessary properties.

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
Chart chart = new Chart();
ChartArea CA = chart.ChartAreas.Add("A1");
Series S1 = chart.Series.Add("S1");
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

S1.Points.AddXY(1, 17);
S1.Points.AddXY(2, 27);
S1.Points.AddXY(3, 7);
S1.Points.AddXY(4, 49);

chart.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
CA.BackColor = chart.BackColor;
CA.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
S1.Points[2]["Exploded"] = "true";
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(chart.Width, chart.Height);
chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.None;
chart.DrawToBitmap(bmp, chart.ClientRectangle);
bmp.MakeTransparent(chart.BackColor);
bmp.Save(yourFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply TaW, but its not the question of how to create a pie chart, the question is how to create any chart/graph without a chart control in place and then save it as an image with transparent background. I have edited my question accordingly. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer. Again, it is up to you to make the chart large enough and set the bitmaps dpi to create a crisp result in the pdf..

Comment: Hey Taw! Thanks for your update! I was busy with other project and hence couldn't work on the update that you had given. Thanks a lot! I did take your suggestions and code, modified a tiny bit with required namespaces and was able to generate the required graph! I have updated the question with answer accordingly! Once again! thanks a lot for your help and follow ups! Cheers!